# Сравнение двух переменных (списков) и исключение похожих результатов

Tags: python

Есть переменная sounds из которой случайным образом выбираются звуки и проигрываются  после проигрывания случайного звука необходимо добавить этот звук в переменную use_sound  и методом сравнения и исключения сделать так чтобы random.choice(sounds) больше не выбирал из списка sounds проигранные звуки. Подскажите пожалуйста  как это можно сделать?

```
#Consonant teams
ch = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ch.wav")
ck = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ck.wav")
dge = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/dge.wav")
gn = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ng.wav")
kn = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/kn.wav")
ng = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ng.wav")
nk = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/nk.wav")
ph = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/ph.wav")
sh = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/sh.wav")
tch = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/tch.wav")
th = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/th.wav")
wh = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/wh.wav")
wr = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/consonant/wr.wav")
#Vowel teams
ai = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/vowel/ai.wav")
au = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/vowel/au.wav")
aw = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/vowel/aw.wav")
ay = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/vowel/ay.wav")
ea = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/vowel/ea.wav")
ee = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/vowel/ee.wav")

sounds = [(ch,"ch"),(ck,"ck"),(dge,"dge"),(gn,"gn"),(kn,"kn"),
         (ng,"ng"),(nk,"nk"),(ph,"ph"),(sh,"sh"),(tch,"tch"),
         (th,"th"),(wh,"wh"),(wr,"wr"),(ai,"ai"),(au,"au"),
         (aw,"aw"),(ay,"ay"),(ea,"ea"),(ee,"ee")]

use_sound = []

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                play_sound = random.choice(sounds)
                play_sound [0].play()
    …
 name = (Вводимый текст с клавиатуры) 
         if name == play_sound [1]:
                        print ("GOOD")
                        use_sound += play_sound 
                        Ctext = False

                    if name != play_sound [1] :
                        print ("BAD")
                        use_sound += play_sound 
                        Ctext = False

    …
```

Comment: Так, может, сразу удалять из списка те файлы, которые уже проиграны?

Comment: Да. Я думаю можно и так. Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: Можно упростить код: `sounds = {p.stem: pygame.mixer.Sound(str(p)) for p in Path().glob('sounds/*/*.wav')}; name = random.choice(sounds); print(name); sounds[name].play(); if name in sounds: print("GOOD")`

Answer (score 1):

Если каждый звуковой файл должен быть воспроизведен только один раз, то можно исключить повторение используя генератор.

```
import random
import glob

def get_sounds():                         # функция - генератор
    sounds = glob.glob('sounds/*/*.wav')) # список файлов
    random.shuffle(sounds)                # случайное перемешивание 

    yield from sounds                     # возврат очередного файла

sounds = get_sounds()                     # создание объекта-генератора

while True:                               # тут ваш цикл обработки событий

    if random.choice([0, 1]):             # ваше условие проверки соответсвия типа события
        try:
            s = next(sounds)              # получение очередного файла
            print(s)
        except StopIteration:             # конец списка файлов
            print('files have ended')
            break
```

Comment: 1- если просто список файлов нужен (.stem атрибут не используется), то можно glob.glob() использовать. 2-  `yield from sounds` вместо цикла.